# How might these prawns have been cooked?

Tags: fish, seafood, safety, cook

[image]

Bought these prawns from Tesco.  It says already cooked but not how, would these typically have been steamed or baked etc.?

When it says ready to eat, does that mean nothing the same way that raw fish is ready to eat since these would not have been reheated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are cooked...likely boiled (sometimes this happens on the boat, sometimes on shore...it depends on the processor), then frozen very quickly.  "Ready to eat" simply means that they are already cooked.  You just need to thaw (though, I suppose you could eat them frozen if you like), and they can be eaten cold.

Comment: They are cooked in seawater on the traditional costal ships  and probably even on the larger ones

Comment: Video: https://youtu.be/xDo8iBfBqI4?t=223 - beginning is raw frozen shrimp, mark 3:43 shows cooking process

Comment: They don't need to be defrosted unless the OP has frozen them. As sold they are suitable for home freezing and have previously been frozen, but ate sold in a defrosted state, https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/301795289